# Dense_rank query in sql(4 different columns) in

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as follows:

```
Sn no.  t_time              Value  rate  
ABC     17-MAY-18 08:00:00  100.00  3
ABC     17-MAY-18 22:00:00  200.00  1
ABC     16-MAY-18 08:00:00  100.00  1
XYZ     14-MAY-18 01:00:00  700.00  1
XYZ     15-MAY-18 10:00:00  500.00  2
XYZ     15-MAY-18 13:00:00  100.00  2
```

And I want to generate the output as follows:

```
Sn no.     New_value
ABC        150
XYZ        450
```

It is grouped by the `Sn no.` The `New_value` is the latest time of each date value multiplied by rate, and then averaged together.
For example ABC `new_value` is
Average of:[(100*1) and (200*1)]

Its a large dataset. How do I write a query for the above in the most efficient way. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytical function(`row_number()`) to achieve the result

```
SQL> WITH cte_table(Snno, t_time, Value, rate) AS (
  2    SELECT 'ABC', to_date('2018-05-17 08:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 100.00, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3    SELECT 'ABC', to_date('2018-05-17 22:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 200.00, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 'ABC', to_date('2018-05-16 08:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 100.00, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5    SELECT 'XYZ', to_date('2018-05-14 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 700.00, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6    SELECT 'XYZ', to_date('2018-05-15 10:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 500.00, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7    SELECT 'XYZ', to_date('2018-05-15 13:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 100.00, 2 FROM DUAL),
  8    --------------------------------
  9    -- End of data preparation
 10    --------------------------------
 11  rn_table AS (
 12    SELECT t.*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(t_time) ORDER BY t_time DESC) AS rn
 13      FROM cte_table t)
 14  SELECT snno,
 15         AVG(VALUE * rate) new_value
 16    FROM rn_table
 17   WHERE rn = 1
 18   GROUP BY snno;
```

Output:

```
SNNO  NEW_VALUE
---- ----------
ABC         150
XYZ         450
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` (or `RANK`/`DENSE_RANK` if it is more appropriate) analytic function in a sub-query and then aggregate in the outer query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81c5e/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Snno, t_time, Value, rate ) AS
SELECT 'ABC', TIMESTAMP '2018-05-17 08:00:00', 100.00, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', TIMESTAMP '2018-05-17 22:00:00', 200.00, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', TIMESTAMP '2018-05-16 08:00:00', 100.00, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ', TIMESTAMP '2018-05-14 01:00:00', 700.00, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ', TIMESTAMP '2018-05-15 10:00:00', 500.00, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ', TIMESTAMP '2018-05-15 13:00:00', 100.00, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT snno,
       AVG( value * rate ) As new_value
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY snno, value
           ORDER BY t_time DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY snno
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81c5e/1/0)**:

```
| SNNO |         NEW_VALUE |
|------|-------------------|
|  ABC |               250 |
|  XYZ | 633.3333333333334 |
```